# C# Insert data from dataset into datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I have 3 rows of data in the database. I loaded these data into a dataset first but failed to load these 3 rows into dgvCustListing. It only loads the last data with 3 blank space on top. Could anyone please point my mistakes?

Thank you.

```
private void LoadCustListing()
    {
        string sQuery = string.Empty;
        int rowcount = 0;
        dgvCustListing.Rows.Clear();
        string spartyConn = ProcessData.GetpartyConnStr();
        using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(spartyConn))
        {
            try
            {
                Conn.Open();
                SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand();
                Cmd.Connection = Conn;
                Cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;


                sQuery = "select pd.Party_Id, pd.Outlet_StoreNo, 'storename', pd.Party_Date, 'time', bc.Child_Name, pd.Party_Status "
                + "from Party_Dtl pd inner join Bday_Child bc "
                + "on pd.Child_Id = bc.Child_Id "
                + "inner join Cust_Dtl cd "
                + "on bc.Parent_Id = cd.Parent_Id "
                + "where pd.Party_Status = 'open' ";

                Cmd.CommandText = sQuery.ToString();
                SqlDataAdapter ExportAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sQuery, Conn);
                ExportAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 10000;
                DataSet DSCust_Listing = new DataSet();
                ExportAdapter.Fill(DSCust_Listing, "Cust_Listing");

                foreach (DataRow DSRow in DSCust_Listing.Tables["Cust_Listing"].Rows)
                {
                    rowcount += 1;
                    dgvCustListing.Rows.Add();
                    dgvCustListing.Rows[dgvCustListing.RowCount - 1].Cells[0].Value = rowcount;
                    dgvCustListing.Rows[dgvCustListing.RowCount - 1].Cells[2].Value = DSRow["Outlet_StoreNo"];
                    dgvCustListing.Rows[dgvCustListing.RowCount - 1].Cells[3].Value = "storename";//DSRow["Outlet"];
                    dgvCustListing.Rows[dgvCustListing.RowCount - 1].Cells[4].Value = DateTime.Parse(DSRow["Party_Date"].ToString());
                    dgvCustListing.Rows[dgvCustListing.RowCount - 1].Cells[5].Value = "time";//DSRow["Party_Time"]; //Time + AMPM
                    dgvCustListing.Rows[dgvCustListing.RowCount - 1].Cells[6].Value = DSRow["Child_Name"];
                    dgvCustListing.Rows[dgvCustListing.RowCount - 1].Cells[7].Value = DSRow["Party_Status"];
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message != "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC")
                {

                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

[click for dgvCustListing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0bGv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use

dgvCustListing.Rows[rowcount  - 1] = .....

.. I think

Answer (score 0):

Instead for iterating the collection and adding row by row, Why not use binding like the following?

```
dgvCustListing.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dgvCustListing.DataSource = DSCust_Listing; // is your dataset
dgvCustListing.DataMember = "Cust_Listing"; // is your table name to bind
```

Since you have only one query to execute, you need not to use a DataSet, instead for that you can use the adapter to populate the result to a DataTable. Let `DTCust_Listing` be that datatable, then you can assign that as `DataSource` for the `dgvCustListing`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a DataSet. A dataSet is an in memory representation of a collection of tables. You can go for a DataTable instead.

declare a Data Table

```
DataTable DSCust_Listing = new DataTable();
```

Instead of looping through the DataSet, just do

```
if(DSCust_Listing != null)
{
    dgvCustListing.DataSource = DSCust_Listing;
    dgvCustListing.DataBind();
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Hi, I tried and this error came out: Error 19 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)